# Colored Pills True MADNESS -V2-

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

This riddle includes a small tweak to [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25856/colored-pills-madness)

This isn't a duplicate. This riddle has one less pill. Because of this, the answer already provided wouldn't work here.

---

You have two bags of similar (weight, texture) solid pills. One bag contains 13 red pills and the other contains 13 green pills. Today, tomorrow, and the day after tomorrow you must select and consume a valid pill set from the following options:

- [3 green pills and 8 red pill]
- [3 green pills and 4 red pill]
- [4 green pills and 3 red pill]

Although you are blind, your colorblind friend is there to assist you. Neither of you know which bag contains which colored pills.

Side effects (Upon you, if and when you are the pill taker):

- When you take an invalid pill set you die.

Side effects (Upon your friend, if and when he is the pill taker):

- Concurrently taking 3 red pills today will instantly blind your friend forever.

  - Consecutively taking 2 red pills today will instantly blind your friend for 24 hours.

    - Taking 1 red pill today will instantly remove a positive memory from your friend for 48 hours.
- Concurrently taking 3 green pills today will instantly fix your friend’s color blindness forever.

  - Consecutively taking 2 green pills today will temporarily fix your friend’s color blindness, tomorrow.

    - Taking 1 green pill today will temporarily fix your friend’s color blindness, the day after tomorrow.
- Taking any number of green pill within a minute after taking any number of red pills will instantly undo the red pill’s side effects. Green pill side effects will still apply.
- Taking any number of red pill within a minute after taking any number of green pills will instantly undo the green pill’s side effects. Red pill side effects will still apply.

**How can you insure the cure of your friend’s colorblindness indefinitely and your survival?**

Comment: [3 green pills and 8 red pill] can never be consumed since there are 13 red pills, even you consume 2x[4 green pills and 3 red pill] after it, there is not enough red pills? Was it intentional?

Comment: @Oray   yes that's intentional.

Comment: Can your friend notice if they regain a positive memory?

Comment: @stephenTG    Yes! Hopefully everyone agrees that's fair.

Comment: The solution to part 1 was "Have the friend take 2 pills, then if he goes blind take 3 of the other pills, otherwise 1 more of the first pill", leaving you with either 10g,13r or 10g,11r. It seems like that solution still works. Worst case you have 10g,11r, day 1 and 2 you take 3g,4r, day 3 you take 4g,3r.

Comment: Expanging on @StephenTG's comment, can your friend notice if they lose a positive memory?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI It was established in part 1 that they cannot

Comment: @Ninety-Three I think, based on the wording, you need to take all three green in one gulp to cure him forever.

Comment: @StephenTG Ah, I was interpreting it simply as "On the same day", if concurrently means "in one gulp" then that's a problem.

Comment: Can you break pills in half to facilitate taking half a red pill and half a green pill? Or is "solid pills" meant to indicate no such shenanigans will be allowed?

Comment: @Ninety-Three sure you can break the pills in half but I'm not sure what that would accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with a 50% chance of the friend losing one positive memory for a bit:

Have your friend label the bags A and B. Get them to take a pill from A and then one from B. If they suddenly remember a positive memory, A is red and B is green. Otherwise, A is green and B is red. Have your friend label the bags.

Have them take 3 green pills, then you take 3 green and 4 red each day, and you're golden.